# Java generics unchecked cast - Possible to check at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
// @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T extractResult(Continuation continuation) {
    Object result = continuation.getAttribute("result");
    return (T) result;
}
```

Is it (at runtime) possible to verify that `result` can be cast to `T`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. To check at runtime, you need an instance of a class, so that you can use [isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29). You don't have access to this using `T` due to type erasure.

Answer (score 3):

Not within this method. All type information related to `T` is erased by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible at runtime, but you need a generic type token. Usually you pass this into the constructor of your generic type

```
class SomeGeneric<T>

private Class<T> token;

public SomeGeneric(Class<T> token) {
    this.token=token;
}
```

Then in your method you can check it at runtime

```
return token.cast(result) // throws ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure will replace `T` with `Object` at runtime. Type information will be absent at runtime so you cannot check against the type.

Answer (score -2):

You could check it by formally try catching a ClassCastException.
It wont make the warning going away though.